# Column unknown firebird c#

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

I have SQL query:

`"SELECT * FROM TB_CLIENTES C JOIN TB_CLIENTES_ENDERECOS E ON (E.CLIENTE_COD = C.CLIENTE_COD AND E.ENDERECO_TIPO_COD =1) WHERE C.CLIENTE_COD LIKE :filtro ORDER BY C.RAZAO_SOCIAL"`

For make select im Using this code:

```
        string conexao = String.Format(integracao.Local, integracao.Usuario, integracao.Senha);
        DbConnection connection = null;
        DbCommand command = null;
        connection = new FbConnection(conexao);
        connection.Open();
        command = new FbCommand(@integracao.ConsultaSQL, (FbConnection)connection);
        if (integracao.TipoFiltro.Equals(TipoFiltroEnum.TEXTO)) { command.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter(":filtro", campoFiltro + "%")); }
        else { command.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter(":filtro", campoFiltro)); }
        DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

im getting this exception:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: 'Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown FILTRO At line 1, column 146' IscException: Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown FILTRO At line 1, column 146
```

EDIT: change : to @filtro and solve problem

Comment: Can you show us what `campoFiltro` is set to?

Comment: just a side note. When you see there are less than 5 questions tagged firebird2.1 in the year of 2018. You know its not a DB that you should use in 2019.

Comment: Good Job Martin, change for @ and solve my problem ty

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in Firebird ADO.net provider should be preceded with the `@` symbol and not a `:`.

Simply change your code to use `@` and it should work.

SQL code snippet:

```
... WHERE C.CLIENTE_COD LIKE @filtro ORDER BY ...
```

C# code snippet:

```
... command.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter("@filtro", ...
```

Comment: I made a small edit, because use of @ for parameter is not a syntax supported by Firebird itself, but by the Firebird ADO.net provider.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for adding the additional clarification to my answer, appreciated